# system of ordinary differential eqs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following system of ordinary differential equations:

$F_1'(t)=-i \lambda \sqrt{n+1}F_2 e^{i \Delta t} $

$F_2'(t)=-i \lambda \sqrt{n+1}F_1 e^{-i \Delta t} $

All paratmeters except $t$ are constants.

support me with a good reference for this please!

Comment: What's $\Delta$?

Comment: $\Delta$ is constant

Answer (score 1):

the answer would be (but not sure):

$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
F_1(t)' \\
F_2' (t)\\
   \end{bmatrix} =
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-i \lambda \exp(i\Delta t) \\
-i \lambda \exp(i\Delta t) & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix} $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
F_1(t) \\
F_2 (t)\\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
then,

\begin{bmatrix}
F_1(t) \\
F_2 (t)\\
   \end{bmatrix}= 
   \begin{bmatrix}
F_1(0) \\
F_2(0)\\
   \end{bmatrix} $$e^{Zt}$$

---

where 
$Z=$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-i \lambda \exp(i\Delta t) \\
-i \lambda \exp(i\Delta t) & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix} $